# How to put Sim808 and a microcontroller on the same PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, pic, altium, gsm

I'm families with **Arduino** (Nano and mini) and **GSM modules** and I've recently Learn about **Altium Designer** and I've designed (and ordered) a few simple PCBs and I've learned about Micro controller and their features and I've assembled GSM tracker with Arduino mini and GSM module.

But now, I want to put the GSM module(sim808 module with castellated edges) and micro controller on a same PCB board so it could be smaller without extra circuits like speaker or microphone.

[image]

My question are:

1- As I'm not families with all **PIC micro controller**(I prefer PIC because I have It's Programmer) , What **DIP** or **SMD**, PIC model is suitable for this project ? Is there any sample schematic with that Micro (Arduino style like it have a lot of schematic samples) That you don't need to read all four hundred page datasheet, which you can just  ignore the part that we don't need on the sample schematics to connect it to another module.

2- I've downloaded SIM8080 datasheet, It shows How to connect each part like power supply or UART, but is there any full schematic to start with?

3- Is it cause issues putting micro and GSM module on the same board, like noise or impedance matching?

**PS**: There is no SIM808 module with full board in the area but I can buy that castellated edge module and I know there are some GSM/Micro controller on the same board, but There is no shipping where I live so its better to build it.